# Connecting one table column to another table column in c# MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sql-server-2008

I new to MVC2 ,I am looking for to post the recent updates in my webpage . 
Can any one give me suggestions , I have  one column  common (that is URl) in two different tables . Iam  looking to connect that column to second table.
Can any one give me linq query like:

**ex:**

- I have in 1st table , columns : date , url, decrption etc..
- 2nd table columns : url , title etc..

I need to put recent updates/events on top  with titles and urls using date column .

Comment: You should show us something that you tried? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this:

```
var query = from t1 in db.table1
            join t2 in db.table2
            on t1.url equals t2.url
            orderby t1.date descending
            select t2.title;
```